# How to check if CustomController.php file exists in Controllers folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I check if my custom controller(AbcContorller.php) file+class and its method(ex. abc() in AbcController) exists in Laravel.

I want to check it from another controller(Ex. XyzController), method(checkAbc()).

Like when I call my route like this:
Route::get('/checkFile', 'XyzController@checkAbc');

checkAbc() method will check if AbcController.php file found or not inside Controllers folder. If found then check if abc() method found or not inside AbcController.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344834/check-whether-laravel-controller-action-is-defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether Laravel Controller Action is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344834/check-whether-laravel-controller-action-is-defined)